# Protractor: How to encrypt passwords passed to the UI automation scripts?

Tags: typescript, encryption, protractor

I am using protractor with typescript for my UI based automation. I want to encrypt password that is passed through a json file(using json format as testdata file) to my specs.
my site password is exposed in the Json file but somehow I want to encrypt the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like it'd be easier to pass the password as an environment variable instead of storing it in a file, but if you still insist to encrypt it here you go:

1. Generate key (password for decryption) and save it in notes (you'll need it to decrypt your password)

```
let uuid = require('uuid');
let key  = uuid();
console.log(key); // 3467f7d0-190f-4319-836e-8918a778d120
```

2. Install [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)
3. Encrypt the password:

```
let CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
let encryptedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('Pa$sword123!', key).toString();
console.log(encryptedPassword); // U2FsdGVkX18iI0gLaeQmf2z7Ev82hMynTo1c2TkCCJo=
```

4. Save it in your json data file

```
{
    'username': 'test-account',
    'password': 'U2FsdGVkX18iI0gLaeQmf2z7Ev82hMynTo1c2TkCCJo='
}
```

5. Wherever you need to use your password do this

```
let CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
let decryptedPassword  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(json['password'], process.env.PASSWORD_KEY).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
await login(json.username, decryptedPassword);
```

6. Run protractor with the following command specifying the decryption key from step #1

```
PASSWORD_KEY=3467f7d0-190f-4319-836e-8918a778d120 protractor protractor.conf.js
```

## P.S.

when I said it's easier to start protractor with password as an environment variable I meant this

```
PASSWORD=Pa$sword123! protractor protractor.conf.js
```

and then refer to password as `process.env.PASSWORD`

Comment: There is also issue with webdriver protocol itself. By default it is HTTP, so sendKeys will send password non-encrypted, and potentially can be read easily red. As well as commands and used values might be written to some commands logs, etc...

Comment: @Sergey Pleshakov Thank you for a nice and detailed answer.